# How to normalize matrix columns in CUDA with max performance?

Tags: performance, matrix, cuda, thrust, cublas

How to effectively normalize matrix columns in CUDA?

My matrix is stored in column-major, and the typical size is 2000x200.

The operation can be represented in the following matlab code.

```
A = rand(2000,200);

A = exp(A);
A = A./repmat(sum(A,1), [size(A,1) 1]);
```

Can this be done effectively by Thrust, cuBLAS and/or cuNPP?

A rapid implementation including 4 kernels is shown as follows.

Wondering if these can be done in 1 or 2 kernels to improve the performance,
especially for the column summation step implemented by cublasDgemv().

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Exp
{
    __host__ __device__ void operator()(double& x)
    {
        x = exp(x);
    }
};

struct Inv
{
    __host__ __device__ void operator()(double& x)
    {
        x = (double) 1.0 / x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig(cudaFuncCachePreferShared);
    cublasHandle_t hd;
    curandGenerator_t rng;
    cublasCreate(&hd);
    curandCreateGenerator(&rng, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);

    const size_t m = 2000, n = 200;
    const double c1 = 1.0;
    const double c0 = 0.0;

    thrust::device_vector<double> A(m * n);
    thrust::device_vector<double> sum(1 * n);
    thrust::device_vector<double> one(m * n, 1.0);

    double* pA = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&A[0]);
    double* pSum = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&sum[0]);
    double* pOne = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&one[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        curandGenerateUniformDouble(rng, pA, A.size());


        thrust::for_each(A.begin(), A.end(), Exp());

        cublasDgemv(hd, CUBLAS_OP_T, m, n,
                &c1, pA, m, pOne, 1, &c0, pSum, 1);

        thrust::for_each(sum.begin(), sum.end(), Inv());

        cublasDdgmm(hd, CUBLAS_SIDE_RIGHT, m, n, pA, m, pSum, 1, pA, m);
    }

    curandDestroyGenerator(rng);
    cublasDestroy(hd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it can be done effectively with CUDA. Show some CUDA code you have written to achieve what you want.

Comment: code added. seek for performance improvement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I compared the performance of 3 approaches on M2090 with CUDA 5.0.

1. [173.179 us] cublas implementation as shown in the question
2. [733.734 us] pure Thrust implementation with `thrust::reduce_by_key` from @talonmies
3. [1.508 ms] pure Thrust implementation with `thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key`

[image: Performance on A_{2,000 x 200}]

It can be seen that,

1. cublas has highest performance in this case;
2. both `thrust::reduce_by_key` & `thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key` launch multiple kernels, which lead to extra overhead;
3. `thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key` writes much more data to DRAM compared to `thrust::reduce_by_key`, which can be one of the reasons for longer kernel time;
4. the main performance difference between cublas and thrust approach is the matrix column summation. thrust is slower possibly because `thrust::reduce_by_key` is designed to do reduction on segments with variant length, but `cublas_gemv()` can only apply to fixed length segments (row/col).

When the matrix A is large enough to ignore the kernel launching overhead, the cublas appoach still performs best. The profiling result on A_{20,000 x 2,000} is shown as follows.

[image: Performance on A_{20,000 x 2,000}]

Fusing the first `for_each` operation with the `cublasSgemv` call as indicated by @talonmies may further improve the performance, but I think kernel written by hand should be used instead of `thrust::reduce_by_key`.

The code for the 3 approaches is shown as follows.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Exp: public thrust::unary_function<double, double>
{
    __host__ __device__ double operator()(double x)
    {
        return exp(x);
    }
};

struct Inv: public thrust::unary_function<double, double>
{
    __host__ __device__ double operator()(double x)
    {
        return (double) 1.0 / x;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct MulC: public thrust::unary_function<T, T>
{
    T C;
    __host__ __device__ MulC(T c) :
        C(c)
    {
    }
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T x)
    {
        return x * C;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct line2col: public thrust::unary_function<T, T>
{
    T C;
    __host__ __device__ line2col(T C) :
            C(C)
    {
    }

    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T i)
    {
        return i / C;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig(cudaFuncCachePreferShared);
    cublasHandle_t hd;
    curandGenerator_t rng;
    cublasCreate(&hd);
    curandCreateGenerator(&rng, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);

    const size_t m = 2000, n = 200;
    const double c1 = 1.0;
    const double c0 = 0.0;

    thrust::device_vector<double> A(m * n);
    thrust::device_vector<double> B(m * n);
    thrust::device_vector<double> C(m * n);
    thrust::device_vector<double> sum1(1 * n);
    thrust::device_vector<double> sum2(1 * n);
    thrust::device_vector<double> one(m * n, 1);

    double* pA = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&A[0]);
    double* pB = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&B[0]);
    double* pSum1 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&sum1[0]);
    double* pSum2 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&sum2[0]);
    double* pOne = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&one[0]);

    curandGenerateUniformDouble(rng, pA, A.size());

    const int count = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        thrust::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), Exp());
        cublasDgemv(hd, CUBLAS_OP_T, m, n, &c1, pB, m, pOne, 1, &c0, pSum1, 1);
        thrust::transform(sum1.begin(), sum1.end(), sum1.begin(), Inv());
        cublasDdgmm(hd, CUBLAS_SIDE_RIGHT, m, n, pB, m, pSum2, 1, pB, m);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        thrust::reduce_by_key(
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), line2col<int>(m)),
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), line2col<int>(m)) + A.size(),
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(A.begin(), Exp()),
                thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
                sum2.begin());
        thrust::transform(
                A.begin(), A.end(),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        sum2.begin(),
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), line2col<int>(m))),
                C.begin(),
                thrust::divides<double>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key(
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), line2col<int>(m)),
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), line2col<int>(m)) + A.size(),
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(A.begin(), Exp()),
                C.begin());
        thrust::copy(
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        C.begin() + m - 1,
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), MulC<int>(m))),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        C.begin() + m - 1,
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), MulC<int>(m))) + n,
                sum2.begin());
        thrust::transform(
                A.begin(), A.end(),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        sum2.begin(),
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), line2col<int>(m))),
                C.begin(),
                thrust::divides<double>());
    }

    curandDestroyGenerator(rng);
    cublasDestroy(hd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to fuse the first `for_each` operation with the `cublasSgemv` call into a single `reduce_by_key` call. If you define/redefine functors as:

```
struct Accessor : public thrust::unary_function<int,int>
{
    int lda;
    __host__ __device__ Accessor(int _lda) : lda(_lda) {};
    __host__ __device__ int operator()(const int& idx)
    {
        return idx/lda;
    }
};

struct Exp : public thrust::unary_function<double,double>
{
    __host__ __device__ double operator()(const double& x)
    {
        return exp(x);
    }
};

struct Inv : public thrust::unary_function<double,double>
{
    __host__ __device__ double operator()(const double& x)
    {
        return double(1.0) / x;
    }
};
```

You can then calculate the normalised output as

```
Accessor columns(m);
thrust::reduce_by_key(
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(int(0)), columns),
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(int(m*n)), columns),
        thrust::make_transform_iterator(A.begin(), Exp()),
        thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
        sum.begin());

thrust::for_each(sum.begin(), sum.end(), Inv());

cublasDdgmm(hd, CUBLAS_SIDE_RIGHT, m, n, pA, m, pSum, 1, pA, m);
```

[disclaimer: all code written in browser and is untested, use at own risk]

Apart from reducing the number of kernel calls, using fancy iterators eliminates the need for the large unit matrix which should reduce memory footprint and total number of memory transactions to do the summation and exponentiation operations.

Comment: The iterators are really _fancy_. I compared the the cublas and thrust approaches. Although `thrust::reduce_by_key` may require lower memory bandwidth, it's still slower compared to the `cublasDgemv`. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that the relative performance will depend quite a lot on what GPU and type you use. On a different GPU using 32 bit types, you might find a reduction approach is closer in performance that the pure CUBLAS implementation. The thrust developers have acknowledged that the state of the art reduction has moved on a bit since they did the current implementation in thrust, but in general the tree like reduction pattern will always be less efficient that something optimal expressed as a stream of FMADs, as in this case.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at trying `thrust::transform` instead of `thrust_for_each`. In some cases (admittedly some time ago), I found it a bit faster than `for_each`. But it probably won't change the performance much.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ArrayFire](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/) in the following manner

```
array A = randu(2000, 2000);
A = exp(A);
A /= tile(sum(A, 0), A.dims(0), 1);
```

You could do this in thrust as well. But if you are going to work with matrices (as opposed to plain vectors), you'd have to do it in a for loop which would not be as efficient.

**DISCLAIMER** I am a developer at Accelereyes, working on arrayfire.

**EDIT** I am working on generating new benchmarks as requested.

**EDIT** We found performance bugs for `exp` in our code because of this benchmark. We are reviewing and fixing it.

Comment: Thanks! It's impressive that the code can be as simple as Matlab.  Could you also compare the performance of  your code with mine? As I don't have the ArrayFire lib on the hand.

Comment: @EricShiyinKang Updated with results.

Comment: I think there's an issue in your benchmark code, which lead to pool timing result for cublas/thrust approach. Here is the modified [bench.cu](https://gist.github.com/786a7ea0597be5ab10d3)

Comment: @EricShiyinKang Any reason you are generating random numbers outside as well as inside the loop ? Also I realized I was not using device synchronize before the timer::stop, causing it to skew results for both thrust and arrayfire. I am working on revising the code again.

Comment: First call to curandGenerateUniformDouble() after curandCreateGenerator() requires extra time as mentioned in [Performance Notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html#topic_1_2_6) of CURAND ref manual.

Comment: m~[500,5000]. n~[100,1000]

Comment: @EricShiyinKang it will take a couple of days for us to fix our bug. If you are interested contact me through the email address in my profile. I updated the answer removing the reference to the benchmarks. I will put new benchmarks here once the fix is publicly available later this week.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Work comes first.